# Show that if f is integrable on every open ball and its integral is 0, then it is true for every jordan set

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, riemann-integration

the question goes like this:

Let $ f: \mathbb R^n \rightarrow \mathbb R $ be a function such that for every open ball $ B \subset \mathbb R^n $, f is integrable on $ B $ and satisfies $$ \int_B f = 0 $$
Prove that for every Jordan bounded set $ E \subset \mathbb R^n $ f is integrable on $ E $ and satisfies: $$ \int_E f = 0 $$

- Jordan bounded sets are sets with negligible (zero measure) boundary.

I'm stuck with the second part of the question, proving that $ \int_E f = 0 $.
I think the way to prove this is to show that for every $ \epsilon > 0 $ we can find open balls $ 
B_1 , \ldots, B_N $ such that $\forall 1\le i\le N: B_i \subseteq E $ and $ Vol(E \setminus \cup_{i=1}^{N} B_i) < \epsilon $, but I did not succeed to prove this.

- $ Vol(F) $ is the volume of the set $ F $.

We have already proven in our class that if $ E $ is a Jordan bounded set, then the same proposition holds except that the balls are replaced with compact cuboids, but I also don't know how to use this to prove the proposition with the open balls.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: "negligible" means "has measure zero"?

Comment: Yes, this is what it means.

Comment: For any bounded subset $E$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$, write $E= \text{Int}\, (E)\cup (E-\text{Int}\, (E))$ be a union of  two disjoint set (indeed $E-\text{Int}\, (E)\subset \partial E$). If $E$ is a bounded Jordan set, then $\lambda (E-\text{Int}\, (E))\leq \lambda (\partial E)=0$, that is to say, $\lambda (E)= \lambda (\text{Int}\, (E)) + \lambda (E-\text{Int}\, (E)) =\lambda (\text{Int}\, (E))$ (since two parts are disjoint). But $\text{Int}\, (E)$ is an open subset in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Your know, in a metric space, an open set $=$ a union of open balls. Thus we have done.

Comment: But it might be not be a union of disjoint open balls and then I couldn't say that $ \int_Ef = \int_{\cup_{i=1}^\infty B_i} f  = \sum_{i=1}^\infty \int_{B_i} f $.

Comment: oh, I see. You need to prove in $\mathbb{R}^n$, any open subset can be written as a countable union of disjoint open balls.

Comment: Maybe you can use disjoint open balls cover an open rectangle, and then use disjoint rectangles cover an open set.

Comment: From searching online, I found that it is not true that every open set can be written as the union of disjoint open balls.

Comment: sorry, maybe I was wrong. in my class, I was told that in $\mathbb{R}^n$ an open set can be written as a countable union of "disjoint" closed rectangles, where "disjoint" means interiors of the closed rectangles are disjoint.

Comment: sorry, maybe you can try Vitali's covering theorem. In the theorem, we use closed balls instead of open balls, but it doesn't matter.